# Invoke some method of result object after mapping in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

Let's say I have the next java class:

```
class User {
    private String loginName;
    private boolean active = true;

    public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
        this.loginName = loginName;
    }

    public void deactivate() {
        this.active = false;
    }
}
```

If I manually map `ResultSet` on this object I would do something like:

```
if (resultSet.getBoolean("col_active") == false) {
    user.deactivate();
}
```

How can I implement this using MyBatis?

Comment: You should do this in SQL. Something like `select coalesce(col_active, 0) active, ... `. MyBatis can set a result to a private field (you might need to edit module-info.java if you use JPMS). If that's not an option, you may have to modify the `User` class or create another intermediate class as there is no way for MyBatis to call the `User#deactivate()` method during mapping.

Comment: Yes, I thought about the intermediate object with `#setActive` method, but looking for a more elegant solution. The second approach would be... to create a "patch" for MyBatis to add something like @Results(customRowMapper = UserMapper.class).